# Is there any way we can elect leader in my application in Kubernetes using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, distributed-system, bully-algorithm

I am trying to implement leader election algorithm in my distributed node.js application.I am using Kubernetes as the container manager and deploying docker containers.I do not have details of host and port of other instances of application running in different pods.

Kubernetes already uses leader election algorithm to choose one leader at a time but my application is inside the container and pod , it is not aware whether i am leader or not. There is one sample code also available to know who is the current leader.

https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/contrib/tree/master/election

This code helps to know which container is the leader but it requires some special privileges to call kubernetes API.

Bully/Ring algorithm can be a solution, but since there is a restriction to not to use any queue/Centralized services like redis or zookeeper as we need another process to run these, but i can use shared filesystem as it will not require monitoring of an extra process.

Not Sure if it is possible to use redis/zookeeper without running a new process and can be done within the application itself.

How can i implement this solution using the application either by pinging them to check if it is down and then make itself to master. In this process lot of race conditions also occur.

I have tried Kubenetes leader algorithm to elect the leader, but due to restricted access to API, it is not possible to use.

Tried Bully algorithm, but since containers are in different pods they are not aware of each other.

Tried Ring algorithm , but the same issue as Bully algorithm.

I expect to implement leader election using any algorithm but without introducing any new processes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [blog post](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/01/simple-leader-election-with-kubernetes/) on how you can achieve that by using a sidecar pattern and a nodejs application